# SQL Server "ORDER BY" optimization - massive performance decrease

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-order-by

Using SQL Server 2000. I have a table that receives a dump from a legacy system once a day, I am trying to write a query that will process this table with a few reference table joins and an order by clause.

This is the SQL I have:

```
select  d.acct_no,
        d.associate_id,
        d.first_name,
        d.last_name,
        d.acct_bal,
        plr.long_name p_lvl,
        tlr.long_name t_lvl,
        d.category,
        d.status,
        tm.site_name,
        d.addr1 + ' ' + isnull(d.addr2,'') address,
        d.city,
        d.state,
        d.country,
        d.post_code,
        CASE WHEN d.home_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.home_phone END home_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.work_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.work_phone END work_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.alt_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.alt_phone END alt_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.email_ok = 1 THEN d.email END email,
        d.last_credit last_paid,
        d.service,
        d.quantity,
        d.amount,
        ar.area_desc area
from    item_dump d
        left outer join territory_map tm on tm.short_postcode = left(post_code,3) and country in ('United States','Canada')
        left outer join p_level_ref plr on plr.p_level_id = d.p_lvl_id
        left outer join t_level_ref tlr on tlr.t_level_id = d.t_lvl_id
        left outer join (select distinct master_item_id, site_item_id from invoice_detail) as map on map.item_id = d.item_no
        left outer join item_ref i on i.item_id = map.master_item_id
        left outer join area_ref ar on ar.area_id = i.area_id
where   (d.cat_id > 80 or d.cat_id < 70)
        and d.standing < 4
        and d.status not like 'DECEASED'
        and d.paid = 1
order by d.associate_id
```

Most of these columns are straight from the legacy system dump table `item_dump`. All the joins are only reference tables with few rows. The legacy table itself has about 17000 records but with the where statements the query comes out to 3000.

I have a non-clustered index on the `associate_id` column.

When I run this query without the `order by associate_id` clause it takes about 2 seconds. With the `order by` clause it takes a full minute!

I've tried adding the `where` clause columns to the index along with `associate_id` but that didn't change the performance at all.

The end of the execution plan without the `order by` looks like this:

[image]

Using `order by`, parallelism kicks in on the order by argument and it looks like this:

[image]

I thought maybe it was [weird SQL Server 2000 parallelism handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477818/sql-server-2000-stored-procedure-prevent-parallelism-or-something), but adding the `(maxdop 1)` hint made the query take 3 minutes instead!

It isn't really sensible for me to put sorting in the application code because this query caches for about 6 hours before it gets run again and I would have to sort it in the application code many times a minute.

I must be missing something very basic but after straining at the query for an hour i.e. running it 10 times, I can't see what it is anymore.

Comment: Table aliases aren't just for JOIN criteria -- then I wouldn't have to ask where `associate_id` is coming from to see if it's from one of the OUTER JOINs (which'd mean it could be NULL).

Comment: @OMGPonies I added dump table aliases so its clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when u remove all the outer joins and ofcourse the select's in there..

```
select  d.acct_no,
        d.associate_id,
        d.first_name,
        d.last_name,
        d.acct_bal,
        d.category,
        d.status,
        d.addr1 + ' ' + isnull(d.addr2,'') address,
        d.city,
        d.state,
        d.country,
        d.post_code,
        CASE WHEN d.home_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.home_phone END home_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.work_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.work_phone END work_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.alt_phone_ok = 1 THEN d.alt_phone END alt_phone,
        CASE WHEN d.email_ok = 1 THEN d.email END email,
        d.last_credit last_paid,
        d.service,
        d.quantity,
        d.amount
from    item_dump d
where   (d.cat_id > 80 or d.cat_id < 70)
        and d.standing < 4
        and d.status not like 'DECEASED'
        and d.paid = 1
order by d.associate_id
```

If that works fast then i would go for sub selects inside the select's

```
select  d.acct_no,
        d.associate_id,
        d.first_name,
        d.last_name,
        d.acct_bal,
        plr.long_name p_lvl,
        tlr.long_name t_lvl,
        d.category,
        d.status,
        (select tm.site_name 
         from territory_map tm 
         where tm.short_postcode = left(post_code,3) 
           and country in ('United States','Canada') as site_name
```

etc. it'll be really faster as left outer joining them in the from clause

Comment: Thanks @rfcdejong. I didn't use the nexted selects but this lead me to the right answer. I found that the query took less than a second with the order by but without the joins and that the invoice_detail table where I do the subselect actually had alot of rows but was masked by the distinct. I added an index to it on the two columns I am using and it is fast now.